# Delete Logged in User RoleAssisgnment using rest api

Tags: permissions, rest, designer-workflow

I want to create a **workflow** which performs the below steps

1. initially break list item permissions,
2. then assign new permissions and
3. after this remove logged in user permissions from the  list item.

I am able to achieve the first 2 steps, but not able to achieve the third step. I am trying to remove all the permissions for the current user assigned to the list item using **REST API**.

Comment: looks like you need to add impersonation here. Create an app step. Ensure that the app has elevated privileges. Use this account to remove the logged in user permission.

http://www.qdoscc.com/blog/sharepoint-tips-app-step-or-impersonation-step-sharepoint-designer-2013

Comment: Can you help me with the rest query to remove logged in user permission

Answer (score 1):

You can use interop bridge. Create another 2010 workflow with **Replace list item permissions** activity and call it from your 2013 workflow.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2012/08/17/how-to-trigger-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-from-a-sharepoint-2013-workflow/